# AngularJS passing Response as header/Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

New to Angular but I am learning.
What my goal is: I have a login view that passes a user object to our API, API checks it against user database and reposnds with Base64 conversion of username and password.  I have Also setup a page that returns some simple JSON if the user passes Authorization : Base ... as a header they will receive the data.  If not it responds 401 and I set up a global 401 handler to route back to "/login".

My issue is that in my LoginService I receive the Base64 key and I can alert it out to show that I received it.  But I get an "undefined" if I inject this service into my json page as a header like so..

```
$http.get('http://myURL/api/project', { headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " +    userLoginService.myData}})
```

So the basic thing I am trying to do is pass data from one SERVICE to another SERVICE,  I have seen how to do this from one CONTROLLER to another but, I am not sure what to do here.  Any sample code would obviously be great.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can share data from one service to another service without passing the data as a parameter to a method or constructor. 
e.g.

```
//inside of a service
this.makeAPIcall = function(token){
    $http.get('http://...', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token}});
}
```

But you likely want to store the authentication key for future http requests anyway and it would be best to store this key in a way that wouldn't require you to ask for authentication each time you need to make a request. I suggest you store your token in the browser's localstorage or as a cookie so that you can retrieve the token through the term for which the user is logged in.

---

---

As a side note, if you find that you're going to have to pass the Authorization header each time you make an API call, you may want to configuring your $httpProvider on the module itself (this example assumes that you are using LocalStorange and that you have an authKey stored in you LocalStorage:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($http, LocalStorageFactory){
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + LocalStorageFactory.get('authKey');
});
```

Comment: In the latter code you posted i notice two big things.  1: You are setting headers in the myApp.RUN method, I thought this was supposed to be done in side of config.  2: You are setting headers with $http.defaults... I thought it was supposed to be done using $httpProvider

Comment: I will play around a bit with storing the token and setting the header in a run method on the app.  I will let you know my results as soon as I  have some :)

Comment: would you mind showing how to save the data response from a srvice to localStorage?

Comment: It can be done in config or in run. I showed it in run so Angular can set up the app's modules and you'd have access to the LocalStorageFactory*. If you're not wrapping localStorage in a factory then you could use config and $httpProvider and insert the auth tokens stored in localStorage.

* Using LocalStorageFactory is optional; I'd wrap its API in a factory to use cookies as a backup. If you're not interested in that then use localStorage from the config and you shouldn't have a problem.

** You can read about the LocalStorage API at [w3s](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

So, what I have done so far: when I get a response from my API I set it as a cookie.  In my service that I use to GET some JSON I set the cookie in the header like so

```
var token = "";
token = $cookieStore.get('token');
 $http({method: "GET", url:"http://example.com/api/project", headers:{'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + token}})
```

However, when I set headers this way, my app doesn't even run the GET. Instead in firebug Console I see

```
Object { transformRequest=[1], transformResponse=[1], method="GET", more...}
```

When I click this I can see that there headers are being set, but the app doesn't perform the GET operation,  so close yet so far away. Any ideas?